# Trying to print out the day of an event using php

Tags: php, printing

Im currently working through the Joy Of PHP book, by Alan Forbes.

As im new to php, I have got stuck on pretty much the first question.

The following program is meant to print out the date of an event, yet it does not.

Can anyone shed any light on why its not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $target = mktime(0,0,0,30,2012);
    $today = time();
    $difference = ($target-$today);
    $days=(int) ($difference/86400);
    print "Our event will occur $days days";
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _why its not working_ What is exactly not working?

Comment: The code works as intended. 
The mktime fucntion takes a time and date, converts it to Epoch (unix time since jan 1 1970) then finds the difference between then and today. It then divides the result by 86400 which is how many seconds there are in a day.

Comment: Only thing is its not coming up when I load up the webpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is one zero to little.

The mktime() has 7 inputs. You use 5, meaning 30 is month and 2012 is day.
What it should be is probably:

```
$target = mktime(0,0,0,8,30,2017);
$today = time();
$difference = ($target-$today);
$days=(int) ($difference/86400);
print "Our event will occur $days days";
```

Here I replaced the year to something more "now". And the output is 14 days. And today it's 14 days til 2017-08-30.
https://3v4l.org/Cl3Yo

[mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)